# Javascript function loop variable

Tags: javascript, function, loops

```js
var i = 99;
while (true)
{
  function lines(him)
  {
    return i + " " + "lines of code in the file " + i + " " + him + i-1 + "lines of code" + "!";
  }
    

  console.log(lines("John strikes one out, clears it all out ;"));
  i -= 1;
  if (i == 0)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble with my function.
Also, if my function is not correct please guide me in the right direction.
I'm also getting a `NaN` error when I run it `( i-1)` I want it to say 99 lines of code in the file 99 lines of code John strikes one out, clears it all out 98 lines of code in the file.

Please be gentle Im new

Comment: I think you should put "him+i-1" in parentheses.

Comment: `+ him + i-1 + ` -> `+ him + (i-1) +`

Comment: @VLAZ Maybe even better. I don't understand what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: `isNaN("string" - 1) === true`  everything up until `-` is being coerced to a string and concatenated.

Comment: @FlatAssembler it's supposed to print the string `him` then follow it with the number `i-1`, e.g., for `i = 9` it should print `8`. But since there are no parentheses anywhere, the *whole* expression is evaluated as a `i + " " + "lines of code in the file " + i + " " + him + i` (which produces a string) -> minus `1` (which produces `NaN`: it's a number subtracted from a string) -> concatenate `"lines of code" + "!"`

Comment: is my function being ran once or 99 times

Comment: @Jackie 99 times. It's just always producing the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're building a string, but then try to subtract one from the string. Subtraction (unlike addition) has to result in a number but `"string"-1` is not a number (NaN).

One way to fix your structure is to put `i-1` in parentheses so it's evaluated separately like this:

```
i + " " + "lines of code in the file " + i + " " + him + (i-1) + "lines of code" + "!"
```

But a nicer syntax is to use backticks to format it in a more readable way. Try this:

```
`${i} lines of code in the file ${i} ${him+(i-1)} lines of code!`
```

I'm not really sure about the structure of the statement but that follows what you seemed to be trying to do. Using backticks with evaluations in `${}` segments makes it easier to read and understand than having string addition.

As further explanation of what went wrong try running the following snippet:

```js
let i = 99
let x = "hello"
console.log("i-1", i - 1)         // Works since i is a number
console.log("x-1", x - 1)         // NaN subtracting from string
console.log("x+i-1", x + i - 1)   // Still NaN since "x+i" is a string
console.log("x+(i-1)", x + (i-1)) // Works since (i-1) is added to the string
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 99;
function lines(him)
{
   return i + " lines of code in the file " + i + " " + him + --i + " lines of code!";
   
}

while (true)
{
   console.log(lines("John strikes one out, clears it all out; "));
   if (!i)
   {
         break;
   }
}
```

This is the way I managed to solve it, pretty long but uses the same logic.

Answer (score -2):

First I'd recommend that you use the correct iteration structure. How to decide which one is the correct for you:

- If you know the number of iterations you are going to have, I'd prefer to use a **for** loop.
- If you have an array as input, you can use `foreach` iterator but I prefer `for` loop instead.
- If you have to iterate until a condition is met, then `while` is the correct structure for this.
- And lastly, if you need to do one thing, and then iterate, then `do` structure is what you need.

In this case, you already know how many iterations you're going to have, so I'd go with a for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    console.log(i + " " + "lines of code in the file " + i + " " + him + i-1 + "lines of code" + "!");
}
```

Also, keep in mind that in your example you are passing the function declaration line 99 times, you should avoid this declaring the function outside the loop structure.

One more thing, you should always try to keep your code as readable as possible, in you actual code, is kind off a hard to read what you are trying to accomplish.